# Javafx IllegalArgumentException: Children : Duplicate children added

Tags: java, javafx, illegalargumentexception

I cant seem to figure out why the duplicate children added error is showing even when i add only one content to the table.

There are 3 main classes :

1. WindowTease : which loads the stage and calls the loadTable() method
2. InventoryController : standard fxml controller, and contains generic loadTable() method
3. InventoryCell : which I use to setcellfactory() for each column.

   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children added: parent = TableRow@6c41701f[styleClass=cell indexed-cell table-row-cell]'null'

Here is my controller :

```
public class InventoryController {

    @FXML protected TableView mainTable;

  public <U> void loadTable(TableCell<U, Component> cellFactory){

    mainTable.getColumns().clear();

    final String[] propertyName = {"id", "invCategory", "quantity", "description", "perItem", "icon"};
    final String[] columnName = {"ID", "Category", "Quantity", "Description", "Price (Per Item)", "Process"};

    for (int i = 0; i < propertyName.length; i++) {
        TableColumn<U, Component> column = new TableColumn<>(columnName[i]);
        column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>(propertyName[i]));
        column.setCellFactory(param -> cellFactory);    //this is the culprit
        //column.setCellFactory(param -> new InventoryCell());   //this shows with no problem
        mainTable.getColumns().add(column);
    }

    ObservableList<Inventory> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    mainTable.getItems().clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        Inventory inve = new Inventory(
                new ID("WSS", i), new Describer("Click me !!"),
                new PercentQuantity(i, 100), new Describer("Click me !!"), new Price(Currency.CHINESE_YEN, i*1000.00),
                new HoverIcon("images/assignment_returned.png"));
        mainTable.getItems().add(inve);
    }

}
```

and here is the Application class :

```
public class WindowTease extends Application {

    @Override
    private void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader());
    loader.setLocation(WindowTease.class.getResource("/layouts/inventory.fxml"));
    InventoryController controller = new InventoryController();
    loader.setController(controller);   
    Parent root = loader.load();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    controller.loadTable(new InventoryCell());

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();            //Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
}
```

and finally the InventoryCell extends TableCell :

```
public class InventoryCell extends TableCell<Inventory, Component>{

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Component item, boolean empty) {
        if (item == null || empty) return;
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        Object node = item.getNode();
        if (node instanceof Node) {
            Node graphix = ((Node)node);
            HBox box = new HBox(graphix);   
            setText("");
            setGraphic(box);

        } else if (node instanceof String) {
            setText((String)node);
            setGraphic(null); 
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**
The culprit is definitely `tablecolumn.setCellFactory(cellfactory);`

Comment: Does your start method pass in the primaryStage?

Comment: yes..sry i forgot to add that while copying

Comment: typically, snippets are not good enough ... what's really needed is a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem ;-) So just guessing: Component.getNode() might be the culprit, that is the node that gets added multiple times to the scenegraph?

Comment: Component.getNode() is definitely not the culprit.I tried with non generic, I narrowed it down and finally figured out that for each column a "new" TableCell must be declared. Thats why one of the lines work while the other doesn't but I cant seem to pin point why that is so.

Comment: as Fabian correctly answered: you need a cellFactory, that is a callback that creates a _new_ cell on every call. You can share the cellFactory across as many columns as you want (provided, the column type is the same). The component's node might (or not - you might get away with it if the node is never shared across items, but even then: if you show it in different columns ... ) turn out a stumbling block in future: as a general rule, _do not_ store nodes in your data item, instead store some raw data that is visualized by a node (in a custom cell factory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called cell**Factory**, not cell**Container** for a reason:

`TableView` uses the `cellFactory` of it's `TableColumn`s to create the nodes to display the data for the column. This is done once for every row displayed.

If you now return the same `TableCell` instance every time, at some point later when the `Skin` of the `TableView` finally assembles the layout, some situation like this will eventually be reached:

```
SomeParent
    |
    |--TableRow1 
    |      |
    |      |--InventoryCell1
    |
    |--TableRow2
           |
           |--InventoryCell1
```

Which isn't allowed, since `InventoryCell1` must not be contained more than once in the scene graph.

Therefore you have to make sure a different `TableCell` instance is returned for every call of the factory.

```
param -> cellFactory
```

Will just return the instance of `TableCell`, that is passed to the `loadTable` method over and over again.

Using method java 8 references you can easily create a factory however:

```
public <U> void loadTable(Supplier<TableCell<U, Component>> cellFactory){
    ...
    column.setCellFactory(param -> cellFactory.get());
```

```
controller.loadTable(InventoryCell::new);
```

Comment: that is what i was thinking fabian. Thanks.